Apache PHP-FPM HTTPS still trying www.sock but it is changed to listen = 127.0.0.1:9081
I have a server, which was not configured by me.
It is working fine with http-access, even php is ok.
When I try with HTTPS I get an error "service unavailable".
Looking in the error logs I see:
[proxy:error] [pid 1503799:tid 1503853] (2)No such file or directory: AH02454: FCGI: attempt to connect to Unix domain socket /var/opt/remi/php81/run/php-fpm/www.sock (*) failed
[proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 1503799:tid 1503853] [client 192.168.1.202:59877] AH01079: failed to make connection to backend: httpd-UDS, referer: https://myhost.mydomain.local/
But the configuration /etc/opt/remi/php81/php-fpm.d/www.conf shows it is listening to listen = 127.0.0.1:9081
not to www.sock (I think it was once configured for www.sock, because there is also a www.conf.bak file which shows this setting).
Why is this error only happening when trying with HTTPS?

The reason for that would be in the configuration of your webserver (apache, nginx, ...), not php-fpm.
